# SQL select multiple lines based on multiple values but one criteria

Tags: sql

This is my first question on a forum but it takes too long to fix my issue.

Explanation:

In the sample if a cost code "C" is in the range the other lines should also be included in the list.

```
INVOICE|VEHICLE|JOB_DATE|COSTCODE|TOTAL|
2017001|UNIT001|01012017|   A    |  100| - OK
2017001|UNIT001|01012017|   C    |  100| - OK
2017001|UNIT002|01012017|   A    |  100| - FALSE
2017001|UNIT002|01012017|   B    |  100| - FALSE
2017001|UNIT003|01012017|   A    |  100| - OK
2017001|UNIT003|01012017|   C    |  100| - OK
2017022|UNIT001|22012017|   A    |  100| - OK
2017022|UNIT001|22012017|   C    |  100| - OK
2017022|UNIT004|22012017|   A    |  100| - FALSE
2017022|UNIT004|22012017|   B    |  100| - FALSE

Expected result:
INVOICE|VEHICLE|JOB_DATE|COSTCODE|TOTAL|
2017001|UNIT001|01012017|   A    |  100|
2017001|UNIT001|01012017|   C    |  100|
2017001|UNIT003|01012017|   A    |  100|
2017001|UNIT003|01012017|   C    |  100|
2017022|UNIT001|22012017|   A    |  100|
2017022|UNIT001|22012017|   C    |  100|
```

The unique value is the combination between "Invoice, Vehicle, Jobdate" then if a line has "Invoice, Vehicle, Jobdate AND **Costcode = "C"**" it should show all lines "**Invoice, Vehicle, Jobdate**" Equal to the line including Costcode "C"

I hope this explanation is a little bit better than my previous.

Table Name is:

```
SELECT INVOICE_KEY_FW,VEHICLE_ID_FW,JOB_DATE_FW,COSTCODE_FW,TOTAL_NETT_FW,
FROM PURCHASE_INVOICE_DETAILS_FW 
WHERE
```

Costs from a certain unit are divided into costs code and performed on a certain day on a certain unit (per invoice). 
We receive bulk invoices where a unit can be on the invoice twice (but never on the same day).
If a cost code (in this case "C") is on an invoice all invoice lines with the same jobdate and the same vehicle ID should be included in the expected result.

Comment: Question is not clear.

Comment: @Amit You could have left off the question mark :-)

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (Or, even worse, links to images.)

Comment: Unable to understand the scenario you're talking about. Please edit the question and ask your problem more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I have no sql editor with me, but this should work.

```
select INVOICE_NUMBER, UNITNUMBER, DATE, COST_CODE, COSTS 
from INVOICE_DETAILS
where UNIT_NUMBER in (select distinct UNIT_NUMBER 
                      from INVOICE_DETAILS
                      WHERE COST_CODE = 'C')
```

I think there is a better way, but I should try before.

Comment: As some mentioned I should explain better (which I tried), but the code you mention did not work. But that's because lack of explanation I guess.

Comment: what I still don't understand is: you say that unique is "Invoice, Vehicle, Jobdate", but in your table it is not unique. Please provide more coherent data, I think I can help. What I understood is that you want to show all the rows having a vehicle with a C... is that right?

Comment: We have an invoice that has many lines with costs per Job. A job is the combination of Vehicle Id and Jobdate (per invoice). On a job when a certain type of cost is booked ("C") we like to see all the costs related. When there is a Job that does not have ("C") we don't like to have this in the list.